# Why there is not a continuous extension $F:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{S}^1$ of the identity map $id: \mathbb{S}^1\to\mathbb{S}^1$?

Tags: general-topology

I'm currently working on Introduction to Smooth Manifolds by Jack Lee. This silly example shows that **Corollary 6.27** about extending smooth functions from closed subsets needs a continuous extension to start with.

The reason for my question is that $id: \mathbb{S}^1 \to \mathbb{S}^1$ is smooth, but if you have a continuous extension to the entire plane, something goes wrong. 
I'm just not seeing it right now, it may be silly of me and I may have done it in the past, but I couldn't see why.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is a continuous onto function from $\mathbb R^2$ to $S^1$: Consider $\mathbb R^2$ as the complex plane, first map it to itself minus the origin by the complex exponential function, then map that to $S^1$ by dividing by the norm.

Comment: @GunnarÞórMagnússon I think the OP wants a continuous extension of the identity function $id: \mathbb{S}^1 \to \mathbb{S}^1$.

Comment: @kccu Yes, I want a continuous extension of the identity. I mean, it supposedly won't exist, but why? :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard answer relies on homotopy theory/algebraic topology.

The existence of such a map $f: \Bbb R^2 \to S^1$ would allow you to define $h: \Bbb S^1 \times [0,1] \to \Bbb S^1$ by $h(x,t) = f(xt)$.  This map would be an example of a homotopy between the identity map on $\Bbb S^1$ and the constant map (sending every point to $f(0)$).

The fact is that no such homotopy can exist, which is also phrased as $\Bbb S^1$ not being a contractible space.  This is usually proved by showing that $\Bbb S^1$ can be distinguished from a point by some homotopical invariant, such as fundamental group.

Comment: You're the best. :) Thank you.